# How can I hide video captions in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html

I have captions setup for my video. As far as I can tell, `textTracks` is the right way to go both for Chrome & FireFox. I can't find anything similar for Safari. Do they expect me to add and remove the tag to hide and show captions?

My code that works in other browsers is simply:

```
function setMode() {
  videoTag.textTracks[0].mode = isOn ? 'showing' : 'hidden';
}
```

On load of page I see this for the `textTracks`:

[image]

It later shows TWO `textTracks` for some reason, where the second is just empty.

[image]

The full code from my latest attempt is:

```js
let isOn = false;
const videoTag = doc.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
const trackTag = doc.createElement('track');
const id = win.ccv$serverData.ccvid;

function setMode() {
  console.log([...videoTag.textTracks]);
  const tracks = [...videoTag.textTracks].filter(t => t.kind === 'captions');
  tracks.forEach(track => {
    console.log('updating', track);
    track.mode = isOn ? 'showing' : 'hidden';
    console.log(track.mode);
  });
}

trackTag.setAttribute('default', '');
trackTag.setAttribute('src', `/api/video/${id}/captions`);
trackTag.setAttribute('kind', `captions`);

videoTag.appendChild(trackTag);

setMode();
```

Comment: On 12, updated question.

Comment: OK. I give up. I honestly don't know why this isn't working, let me know if you find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the `<track>` elements:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("track")].forEach((track) => track.remove());
```

An alternative is to use CSS:

```
track {
  display: none !important
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. I was hoping there was a more standard way. Seems Safari is really falling behind. Or it is likely a bug.

Comment: Does  it work? If not, what version of Safari are you using? According to MDN the `TextTrack` API [is supported in Safari 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I'm on 12 and confused why it doesn't show up. This solution will work, but it seems to be a patch. Hoping I can find what I might be doing wrong. Maybe Safari is being extra secure and I'm not doing something it expects for me to access that?

Comment: Also, if I remove and then add back, Safari doesn't start to re-render them.

`document.getElementsByTagName('track')[0].style.display = 'none !important';` did nothing.

`const style = document.createElement('style');
style.type ="text/css";
style.innerText = 'track { display: none !important }';
document.body.appendChild(style);` did nothing either.

Comment: Have you tried using classes? For example, adding a class to hide it and remove it to show it, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I almost have it. Will be posting shortly.

Answer (score 1):

So you can notice my code is doing `[0]` which I tend to avoid. But I was manually appending one `track`. Apparently Safari is adding another `track` for `captions` - even when my tag says its `kind` is `captions`.

So in the case where there is only one tag, there are still two track lists.

If someone can explain why Safari might do this, I'd change the answer to theirs. Or maybe this is a bug?

I found the method `onaddtrack` in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/texttracklist/1632931-onaddtrack.

This made my solution become: `videoTag.textTracks.onaddtrack = setMode;`

I obviously also had to remove the `videoTag.textTracks[0].mode = isOn ? 'showing' : 'hidden';` bit in favor of

```js
  const tracks = [...videoTag.textTracks].filter(t => t.kind === 'captions');
  tracks.forEach(track => {
    track.mode = isOn ? 'showing' : 'hidden';
  });
```

Comment: Just saw your update and this is the first time I can say: *"it was the browsers fault"* and not be wrong. Congrats on finding the solution!